# insert json object to data lake

Tags: python, azure, stream, azure-data-lake

i have few  python api endpoints thet get data in request body . i want to insert/add this data to azure datalake every time api call any ideas?

example api endpoint

```
 @main.route("/order/add", methods=["POST"])
    def post_add_new_order():
    data = request.json
    for key in data:
        if not typesModule.key_type_and_value_type_are_equal(key, data[key]):
            return {"err": "One of the value types is incorrect"}
```

want to insert this data to azure data lake

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add data to  Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 in python package, we can use the package `azure-datalake-store` to implement it.

For example

1. Create a service principal

```
az login
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n 'Myapp' --skip-assignment
```

2. Assign the service principal to the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 account file or folder access control.

The ACL for Azure data lake gen1 has three permissions. There are **Read, Write, and Execute**. Please configure it according to your need. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-access-control) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-service-to-service-authenticate-using-active-directory)

3. Code

```
import json

import azure.datalake.store.lib as lib
from azure.datalake.store.core import AzureDLFileSystem

RESOURCE = 'https://datalake.azure.net/'
client_id = '42e0d***c4c522d988c4'
client_secret  = 'Gbx2eK6****ClJDfQpIjoae:'
tenant = 'e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb'

 @main.route("/order/add", methods=["POST"])
    def post_add_new_order():
        data = request.get_json()
        json_data = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
        adlCreds = lib.auth(tenant_id = tenant,
                client_secret = client_secret,
                client_id = client_id,
                resource=RESOURCE)
        
        adlsFileSystemClient = AzureDLFileSystem(adlCreds, store_name='testbowman')
        # check if the file exist 
        if adlsFileSystemClient.access('/test/data.json'):
            #append content
            with adlsFileSystemClient.open(path='/test/data.json', mode='ab') as f:
                f.write(json_data)
                f.write(b'\r\n')
        else:
            #create file and write
            with adlsFileSystemClient.open(path='/test/data.json', mode='wb') as f:
                f.write(json_data)
                f.write(b'\r\n')
        return {'you sent' : data}
```